# Compile and run Servlet from command prompt

Tags: java, servlets, command-prompt

It's straightforward. I want to compile all class when make a web application with Servlet and Jsp. pure 100% command prompt. How do I do that? Someone can give me some demo or any document?

Comment: Well, you just have to use `javac` and add the servlets-api.jar to the classpath. It's like compiling any other class from command line.

Comment: As you say, It works okay. But when I create Custom class. Bird, Tiger, Chicken for example. Then a Servlet class imports 3 classes. I would compiled 3 classes first. Then I compiled the Servlet class. Can I just compiles all stuff at same time?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just read more about `javac` usage

Answer (score 2):

compile all servlets then you will get .class files.then put these .class files in classes folder of your application.

you need to follow correct directory structure as follows:

```
project_name
        WEB_INF
             classes
             lib
             web.xml
        index.jsp
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a tool that combine compilation, resource management, building of the war and optionnaly deployment. [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a nice tool, but you could also use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). The latter is less configurable but more straightforward.

Both can be integrated in an IDE (Eclipse or Netbeans), or can be runned directly from command ling.

Comment: You should answer his question, then provide these extra information regarding **why** using such a tool is better.

Answer (score 1):

once see this link, i think this is useful to you

http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Servlet-Interview-Questions/20285-how-to-compile-and-run-servlet-program-.html

Comment: Add more details in this post.